# error: no suitable constructor found for FileDialog(Notepad,String,int)

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class Notepad implements ActionListener {
    Frame f;
    MenuBar mb;
    Menu m1, m2;
    MenuItem nw, opn, sve, sveas, ext, fnd, fr;
    TextArea t;

    // [...Constructor removed...]

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == nw) {
            t.setText(" ");
        } else if (e.getSource() == opn) {
            try {
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Open File", FileDialog.LOAD); // <- Does not compile
                fd.setVisible(true);
                String dir = fd.getDirectory();
                String fname = fd.getFile();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dir + fname);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
                String str = " ", msg = " ";
                while ((str = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                    msg = msg + str;
                    msg += "\n";
                }
                t.setText(msg);
                dis.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
    // [...]
}
```

I get:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for FileDialog(Notepad,String,int)
         FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(this,"Open File",FileDialog.LOAD);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(this,"Open File",FileDialog.LOAD);` wrong.

This first param must be a `Frame` which is the parent. maybe use:

```
FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(f,"Open File",FileDialog.LOAD);
```

Plz look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html

Answer (score 1):

```
FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(this,"Open File",FileDialog.LOAD);
```

You're using `this` as the first parameter, and `this` refers to the instance of the class you are currently working on, so to a `Notepad`. For example if you use, somewhere else in your code:

```
Notepad np = new Notepad();
//...
np.actionPerformed(ae); //ae is an ActionEvent
```

Then `this` refers to `np`. You should use

```
FileDialog fd=new FileDialog(f,"Open File",FileDialog.LOAD);
```

EDIT: Another user preceded me with a very similar answer, sorry